# $SU(3)$ and $SU(3)\times SU(2)\times U(1)$ Symmetry Breaking

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, gauge-theory, group-theory, symmetry-breaking

For my master's project I was doing spontaneous symmetry breaking in which I covered U(1), SU(2), SU(2)×U(1) symmetry breaking. My supervisor has said that for the project this much is enough. But now I am curious and want to learn more. So I have decided to do SU(3) and SU(3)×SU(2)×U(1) symmetry breaking by myself but I am not able to find any source for this. Can anybody suggest some good resources for these topics?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/141852/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/509713/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Please do not completely edit a question to completely change what it is asking.  (I've rolled back this revision.)  If you have a new question, please ask it using the "Ask Question" button at the top right of the page.